# I want it to skip the missing files and continue executing, while downloading a file via get request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am not familiar with error handling in python/get.req,
I am trying to write a function which downloads files from a dynamic URL which has dynamic {date}.
When I run it in loop i.e date range, It stops where the files are missing.
I want it to skip the missing files and continue executing.

---

Code:

```
def download(url: str, dest_folder: str):
    if not os.path.exists(dest_folder):
        os.makedirs(dest_folder) 

    filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "_")  
    file_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, filename)

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.ok:
        print("saving to", os.path.abspath(file_path))
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()
                    os.fsync(f.fileno())
    else:  # HTTP status code 4XX/5XX
        print("Download failed: status code {}\n{}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To handle an error, you need `try` and `except`.

`try` is like an `if`: you put a `try:` and then after it you put the whole code (with the correct indentation).

Then, you put an `except:` (like an `else`), and the code after the `except` is going to be executed when an error occurs.

#### With this being said, it's time for the alternative code (in case of error).

To terminate the program when the error occurs, you can use, for example, `os._exit(0)`, which exits with no error.

If you want to ignore the error (in case you just want to test or see what happens next), you must change `except:` for `except Exception as e:` and then add `print(e)`. You can also add text to the `print()`, i.e. `print("An error has occurred: " + e)`/`print(f"An error has occurred: {e}")`.

Now I read your code and I see I was wrong. If you want to use an `if` check, um... I don't understand it very well. What exactly do you want to do?

Code with `continue` (which might work, but I didn't test it):

```py
def download(url: str, dest_folder: str):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(dest_folder):
            os.makedirs(dest_folder) 

        filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "_")  
        file_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, filename)

        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if r.ok:
            print("saving to", os.path.abspath(file_path))
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
                    if chunk:
                        f.write(chunk)
                        f.flush()
                        os.fsync(f.fileno())
        else: # HTTP status code 4XX/5XX
            print("Download failed: status code {}\n{}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
            continue
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed: error {}".format(e))
        continue
```

Comment: It has the error now: 
'continue' not properly in loop . 

By "if check" I'm trying to check if the req is OK and then print "Ssaving to <path>" and then save it to the dest_folder.

Comment: Try removing `continue` from the else, change it for a `pass`.

Comment: It doesn't throw error , saves only 3 files and gets in loop forever... :(

Comment: I replaced continue with "pass" and it works :-)
Thank you very much~

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use try/except method. Can you try your codes like this:

```
try:
  if not os.path.exists(dest_folder):
    os.makedirs(dest_folder) 

    filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "_")  
    file_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, filename)

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.ok:
      print("saving to", os.path.abspath(file_path))
      with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
          if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
            os.fsync(f.fileno())
except:
    print("Download failed: status code {}\n{}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.
The code still gets stuck at the missing files. 
I want to use "continue" in a way which would allow to continue downloading for the other files except the failed ones.

Comment: Yes, "continue" can be work.  That's so cool!

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't halts or continues after erroe, its just in a loop forver, I tried using "pass" too, ain't work!